# Performance for query filtered by user preference

Tags: performance, mariadb, innodb, cache, query-cache

I have an app, that shows data based on user preference. I will simplify it in this theoretical example:

**The app shows articles filtered based on user preference for their favorite authors or their favorite topics.** The data will be updated with high frequency since there will be new articles published any minute.

The approach I am going for now: The app makes a request to an endpoint with user favorites in the url params like this:

- `https://example.com/api/articles/today?=fav_autohrs=1,5,3,7,10&topics=3,6,9`

My query to db is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles_table
WHERE 
author_id IN (1,5,3,7,10) OR topic_id IN(3,6,9)
AND (published_datetime BETWEEN '$date_today 00:00:00' AND '$date_next 00:00:00')
```

And I am creating an index for columns: published_datetime & author_id & topic_id.

What I want to know if there is any caching mechanism or improvements I can do to this approach to achieve best performance and best utilization of db resources?

My database server run on AWS RDS t3.medium that has 2 cpus and 4GB of ram. And I am expecting a high number of requests that reach thousands per minute, so I want to be sure I am solid about my approach and what I need to improve before I publish it to production.

I am currently caching http requests for a short ttl, with varnish. But this won't help much in this case since most requests will be unique in their combination of preference.

***My setup:***

- WordPress - as CMS & REST API
- Varnish - as caching layer
- Mariadb - as database
- InnoDB - as table engine

**Whats the best approach for my case to allow users to query db based on preference with optimal caching?**

**Edit:**
I tested my query to see how fast they run and got:

- 0.0117s on user first request with preference (unique).
- 0.0040s when another request is made to a new date after the first request (preference unchanged, date changed).

is this considered good?

Comment: I edited to make it clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are not the same product. They're not even compatible in many cases. MariaDB started in 2010 as a fork of MySQL 5.5, but both products have changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

> My query to db is something like this:
> author_id IN ('1,5,3,7,10') OR topic_id IN('3,6,9')

Hopefully only *something* like that.
Double check you "IN" clause syntax - I doubt you have an topic_id of '3,6,9'.

As to performance ...

"WHERE .. IN" can present problems of its own, particularly with long lists of values but there's probably not much you can do about that one.

Another operator that might perform *surprisingly* badly is "OR".  Finding records based on this condition or that one (or some other one) forces the database to "second-guess" itself and choose less efficient scanning plans.  Breaking the query down into simpler, "all-inclusive" conditions and then "bolting" the results back together is what the database prefers.

You might try this as an alternative:

```
SELECT *
  FROM articles_table
  WHERE author_id IN ( 1, 5, 3, 7, 10 ) 
  AND published_datetime BETWEEN '$date_today 00:00:00' AND '$date_next 00:00:00'
UNION 
SELECT *
  FROM articles_table
  WHERE topic_id IN ( 3, 6, 9 ) 
  AND published_datetime BETWEEN '$date_today 00:00:00' AND '$date_next 00:00:00'
```

Or, to reduce the load on the duplicate-removing "UNION":

```
SELECT * 
from articles_table 
where article_id in 
( SELECT article_id
    FROM articles_table
    WHERE author_id IN ( 1, 5, 3, 7, 10 ) 
    AND published_datetime BETWEEN '$date_today 00:00:00' AND '$date_next 00:00:00'
  UNION 
  SELECT article_id
    FROM articles_table
    WHERE topic_id IN ( 3, 6, 9 ) 
    AND published_datetime BETWEEN '$date_today 00:00:00' AND '$date_next 00:00:00'
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for this point, do you recommend any caching mechanism on the backend side for this use case?
I can think of splitting the request into multiple requests for each author and topic so I can cache it, but that might end up with hundred of requests if the user has many preferences.

Comment: The database is /already/ using a caching mechanism - its Buffer Cache.  
Data Pages are loaded into memory as they are needed and will stay there until they get removed to make spaces for new ones.  The more "popular" a Data Page is, the more likely it is to /stay/ in the Buffer Cache.  Multiple queries (i.e. select statements) may be counter-productive - every "round-trip" to the database takes time and they all add up. The very Worst Case - the "1+N Query" model - is an Application Killer.

Answer (score 1):

"Caching" usually involves *exactly the same* query being run twice.  Probably different users are looking for slightly different things, hence a caching layer is likely to be useless.

MariaDB (and MySQL) use a cache called the "buffer_pool".  This is at a lower level, hence still useful when different users are fetching different info.  It is tuned by `innodb_buffer_pool_size` which may have a terribly low setting of 128M.  Change it to 1500M.

As already discussed, `IN` with a quote string is simply wrong.  `IN` a list of numbers is inefficient, `OR` is 'impossible' to optimize, though `UNION` helps.  Also, the date range is also a drag on performance.

The only way the Optimizer will run your query is by checking every row in the table.  In some situations, one of these may help; add them all:

```
INDEX(author_id)
INDEX(topic_id)
INDEX(published_datetime)
```

The column names don't look like WordPress, is that really the app?

Will you also have `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT`?

11.7ms sounds great for a `SELECT` like yours.

One new new article per minute is not a problem; even one per second is not a problem.

But the bigger the table gets, the slower the query will be.

Comment: Thank you for the input, yes I am already indexing the columns as mentioned in the question.
I am using also `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`, its not affecting performance.
I will look further into tuning `innodb_buffer_pool_size` thanks.